# how to use variable inside laravel @include?

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

```
{{$one = 'testFileName'}}

@include('folder.project.$one')
```

Comment: `@include("folder.project.$one")` note the double quotes. it's basically PHP string rules

Comment: To explain ^^, double quotes will evaluate variables in a string. See http://php.net/string

Comment: or you could use like `@include("folder.project.".$one)` and if you want to pass `$one` to `folder.project` then you can pass it as second parameter

Answer (score 5):

You can do that

First solution

```
{{$one = 'folder.project.testFileName'}}

@include($one)
```

second solution

```
{{$one = 'testFileName'}}

@include("folder.project.$one")
```

third solution

```
{{$one = 'testFileName'}}

@include("folder.project." . $one)
```

And for define variable you can also use

```
@php
    $one = 'testFileName';
@endphp
```

or (but it can depends of laravel version)

```
@php($one = 'testFileName')
```

Answer (score 1):

First define variable in PHP tag (not {{ }})

```
@php($one = 'testFileName')
```

Second Use variable :

```
@include('folder.project'.$one)
```